# SimpleXML outputs unicode in a strange way

Tags: php, unicode, internationalization, simplexml, cyrillic

I use simpleXML to process xml file. It has Cyrillic characters. I also use `dom_import_simplexml`, `importNode` and `appendChild` to copy trees from file to file and place to place.
At the end of processing I do `print_r` of resulting `simpleXmlElement` and everything is ok. But I also do `asXml('outputfile.xml')` and something strange is going on: all cyrillic characters that was not wrapped with `CDATA` (some tags bodies and all attributes) change to their unicode code.

For example, the output of `print_r` (just a fragment):

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array 
             ( [NAME] => Государственный аппарат и     механизм 
               [COSTYES] => 3.89983579639 [COSTNO] => 0 
               [ID] => 9 )
           [COMMENTYES] => Вы совершенно         правы. 
          [COMMENTNO] => Нет, Вы ошиблись. ) ) )
```

But in file that `asXml` generates, i get something like this:

```
<QUEST NAME="&#x422;&#x435;&#x43E;&#x440;&#x438;&#x44F;#x434;&#x432;&#x443;&#x445;&#x43C;&#x435;&#x447;&#x435;&#x439;"     
    style="educ" ID="1">
  <DESC><![CDATA[Теория происхождения государства, известная как теория "двух мечей" [2, с.40], 
    представляет из себя...
  ]]></DESC>`
```

I set utf-8 locale everywhere it's possible, googled every combination of words "simplexml, unicode, cyrillic, asXml, etc" but nothing worked.

**UPD** Looks like some function used does `htmlentities()`. So, thanks to [voitcus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2088851/voitcus), the solution is to use `html_entity_decode()` as adviced [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php#107137).

Comment: Please read the discussion (comments) in the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php

Comment: For example [this one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php#107137)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I wonder now, how I didn't come to this solution by my own.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder you might not declare encoding when you imported xml document at first. The following two give you different output.

```
$simplexml = simplexml_load_string('<QUEST NAME="Государственный" />');
if (!$simplexml) { exit('parse failed'); }
print_r($simplexml->asXml());

$simplexml = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><QUEST NAME="Государственный" />');
if (!$simplexml) { exit('parse failed'); }
print_r($simplexml->asXml());
```

SimpleXMLElement object knows its own encoding from the original xml declaration, and if it was not declared, it generates numerical character references for safety, I guess.

Comment: The encoding was declared in xml file and the same encoding was set as locale. The problem was in `htmlentities`, see the comments to my post and update in it.

Comment: Please run my sample. The second one does not encode them even without CDATA. You may need to make the shortest code to reproduce your problem which doing importNode/appendChild thingy.